# pd.merge throwing error while executing through .bat file

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, batch-file

Python script does not run while executing in a bat file, but runs seamlessly on the editor.

The error is related to datatype difference in pd.merge script. Although the datatype given to both the columns is same in both the dataframes.

```
df2a["supply"] = df2a["supply"].astype(str)
df2["supply_typ"] = df2["supply_typ"].astype(str)
df2a["supply_typ"] = df2a["supply_typ"].astype(str)
df = (pd.merge(df2,df2a, how=join,on= 
['entity_id','pare','grome','buame','tame','prd','gsn',                                                    
'supply','supply_typ'],suffixes=['gs2','gs2x']))
```

While running the bat file i am getting following error in pd.merge:

You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but contains code that cannot be formatted in a comment, and should be enough to solve the problem.

When pandas says that *you are trying to merge on float64 and object columns*, it is certainly right. It may not be evident because pandas relies on numpy, and that a numpy *object* column can store any data.

I ended with a simple function to diagnose all those data type problem:

```
def show_types(df):
    for i,c in enumerate(df.columns):
        print(df[c].dtype, type(df.iat[0, i]))
```

It shows both the pandas datatype of the columns of a dataframe, and the actual type of the first element of the column. It can help do see the difference between columns containing `str` elements and other containing `datatime.datatime` ones, while the datatype is just `objects`.

Use that on both of your dataframes, and the problem should become evident...

Comment: if that's the case then how come it is working while running the script on spyder. It is throwing error only on bat file.

Comment: As it breaks, you can alway add a trace print to help to do a diagnostic. When it is fixed, just comment the debug only print statements.

Comment: i added a print statement to check if data type is changed. But it prints same data type as in string for both .

Comment: @NikitaRathi: The **9** columns your are merging on are all strings?

Comment: no..but the error is coming for supply_typ and supply colum

Comment: @NikitaRathi: please add the full error message (including the stack trace) to your question.

Comment: Hi, It seems there was a data type issue . Using df.dtypes i checked all datatypes and found some of the columns in df2 had a different data type from df2a dataframe.

Comment: after equating  datatypes of all columns in both df it worked sucessfully.